# How do I get keys in where is my water?

Tags: wheres-my-water

I'm playing where is my water on windows phone. I completed my missions under "soap factory", and four more missions under "beach". It wants me buy 3 keys or take from my friends.
Is there any way to get keys, with out buying them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is not. But your friends don't need keys to gift you a key. You basically just need 3 friends to move onto the beach.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is actually. you can watch those 3 ad videos.
The 24-hour gap between each video but you can just change the date set.
Though you do need a lot of patience for those videos